# Rails 3.2 Active Record Join: Record not showing up

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My models have a many-to-many relationship where Coach could have coached many Teams, and a Team could have multiple coaches.(Assistant, Head, etc)

in Rails Console, when I run:

```
 @coach = Coach.joins(:teams).select("coaches.first_name, coaches.last_name, teams.team_level")
```

returns:

```
 => [#<Coach first_name: "john", last_name: "doe">]
```

notice that it doesnt return the `teams.team_level`, so I cant use `@coach.team_level` on my view

When I do `.to_sql` it returns:

```
=> "SELECT coaches.first_name, coaches.last_name, teams.team_level 
FROM `coaches` 
INNER JOIN `coach_teams` ON `coach_teams`.`coach_id` = `coaches`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `teams` ON `teams`.`id` = `coach_teams`.`team_id`
```

Which is what I expect... So when I run this Query against my DB, I get the expected fields.

What am I doing wrong here/what am I not seeing? Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, you use a method of the `Coach` model so you get `Coach` model/s.

Since you're using a join on teams you can access the `team_level` value without an additional query.

Comment: Well thats what I thought, but if I do `@coach = Coach.joins(:teams).select("coaches.first_name, coaches.last_name, teams.team_level")` and follow that by `@coaches.team_level`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'team_level' for [#<Coach first_name: "john", last_name: "doe">]:ActiveRecord::Relation`, thoughts?

Comment: I dont know what I didnt, but @coaches.team_level magically works now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually good. You ask for a Coach model, you join the Team model with it.

So you actually just need `@coach.teams.team_level` to access the team level.

The select can't change the schema of your modell, it can only filter down the attributes returned form the SQL, this way you need less roundtrip and less data transfer, but the structure is unchanged.

Comment: tried that but I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'players' for [#<Coach first_name: "john", last_name: "doe">]:ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: I dont know what I didnt, but @coaches.team_level magically works now. thanks!